# Can I generate html templates from models

Tags: python, django

I know we can generate Database Tables from models, which enables a fast development. 
Can we also generate HTML templates from models, such as list/add/edit?
You know we can do this in Grails.  Hopefully we can also do that in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/).

Comment: with generic views I still have to write HTML pages

Comment: Sure, but that's the easy part. Just extend your base template and write a line or 2 for the form.

Answer (score 1):

- For a list page, you could just generate a table.
- For an add/edit page, use Django Forms.

Comment: If you don't know, then is the first sentence in your question talking about?